# Where can I get the source code for "Ubuntu for phones"?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

It says in your website that Ubuntu is a free operating system.

How can I get the source code for "Ubuntu for phones"?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

You can follow the instructions for building Ubuntu Touch from source from [this wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Building).

Building from source is quite an involved process, involving getting Android drivers and flashing a mobile device, which is why I'm not going to attempt to summarise it here. Just follow the link, it's a wiki so hopefully it will be kept up-to-date.

If you just want to try developing Ubuntu Touch apps on your desktop, you don't need to build Ubuntu Touch from source, you just need the [Ubuntu Touch SDK](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/).